# how to send all the list view items to the server in android

Tags: android

I cant send all the rows of list view,Every time just last row of list view is going to the server,i want send all the items of list view when i click place order button.here is edited code my  full code:

```
public class Order_From_App_All_new extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog
   ArrayList<Actor> productlist = new ArrayList<>();
    TextView txt1;


    Button order;
    ListView listview;
    ImageView ivImage;
    EditText edt2;
    String address;
    TextView txt17;
    int position;
    String product_id;
    String product_qty;
    ListView listview1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.orderfromapp);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
       order=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        edt2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
       ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
         adapter = new Product_Adapter(Order_From_App_All_new.this,    R.layout.row1, productlist);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
       new DownloadJSON().execute();
       order.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    // @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:


            product_name = (String) mySpinner.getSelectedItem();

            String product_quantity = edt1.getEditableText().toString();

            String addtocartquerystring = "?product_name=" + product_name + "&product_quantity=" + product_quantity;


            Log.d("Request : ", "starting 00 " + CC14.GETURL17 + addtocartquerystring);
            new GetAddToCart(this, CC14.GETURL17 + addtocartquerystring).execute();
             break;


            case R.id.button4:
                 address=edt2.getEditableText().toString();


               String[] productid = new String[productlist.size()];
                String[] productquantity = new String[productlist.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < productlist.size(); i++) {



                    productid[i]=productlist.get(i).getProductid();
                    productquantity[i]=productlist.get(i).getProductquantity();
                    product_qty=productquantity[i];
                    product_id=productid[i];


                }

             String placeorderquerystring = "?address=" + address + "&product_id=" + product_id+"&product_qty="product_qty;


                   Log.d("Request : ", "starting 00 " + CC14.GETURL23 + placeorderquerystring);
                   new GetPlaceOrder(Order_From_App_All_new.this, CC14.GETURL23 + placeorderquerystring).execute();

                    break;
                    default:
                        break;

        }
    }
public class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Locate the WorldPopulation Class
        // productlist = new ArrayList<>();
        // Create an array to populate the spinner
        spinnerlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        // JSON file URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("http://duraent.net/android_order_app/api/android/orderList.php");

        try {
            // Locate the NodeList name
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("product");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                spinnerlist.add(jsonobject.optString("productname"));

                // Actor actors = new Actor();

                //  actors.setProductname("Productname", jsonobject.optString("Productname"));

                // actors.setDirectmobileorderprice("directmobileorderprice", jsonobject.getString("directmobileorderprice"));

                // productlist.add(actors);

                //Populate spinner with country names


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the spinner in activity_main.xml
        Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);


        // Spinner adapter
        mySpinner
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Order_From_App_All_new.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        spinnerlist));


    }


}

public class GetAddToCart extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    Http_OrderFromAppNew request = new Http_OrderFromAppNew();
    Context ctx;
    ListView listview;
    TextView txt1;
    String latLong_url;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    private String json;

    public GetAddToCart(Context _ctx, String _latong_url) {
        ctx = _ctx;
        latLong_url = _latong_url;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Order_From_App_All_new.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Locate the WorldPopulation Class

        // Create an array to populate the spinner
        // spinnerlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        // JSON file URL address
        String json = request
                .makeHttpRequest(latLong_url, "GET", null);


        // Populate spinner with country names
        Log.d("Request Login attempt", json.toString());

        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
        // Locate the spinner in activity_main.xml
        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(json);
            // Locate the NodeList name
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("product");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // spinnerlist.add(jsonobject.optString("productname"));

                Actor actors = new Actor();

                actors.setProductname("productname",jsonobject.getString("productname"));

                actors.setProductid("productid",jsonobject.getString("productid"));
                actors.setSellingprice("sellingprice",jsonobject.getString("sellingprice"));
                actors.setPricetotal("pricetotal", jsonobject.getString("pricetotal"));
                actors.setProductquantity("productquantity", jsonobject.getString("productquantity"));


                productlist.add(actors);
                adapter.changeData(productlist);


                // ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                //adapter = new Product_Adapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row1, productlist);
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                //listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();


            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}


    public class GetPlaceOrder extends AsyncTask<String, String,String> {

        Http_OrderFromAppNew request = new Http_OrderFromAppNew();
        Context ctx;
        ListView listview;
        TextView txt1;
        String latLong_url;
        ProgressDialog pd;
        private String json;

        public GetPlaceOrder(Context _ctx, String _latong_url) {
            ctx = _ctx;
            latLong_url = _latong_url;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Order_From_App_All_new.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // Locate the WorldPopulation Class

            // Create an array to populate the spinner
            // spinnerlist = new ArrayList<String>();
            // JSON file URL address
            String json = request
                    .makeHttpRequest(latLong_url, "GET", null);


            // Populate spinner with country names
            Log.d("Request Login attempt", json.toString());

            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
            // Locate the spinner in activity_main.xml
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            try {
                TextView txt17=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView17);
                txt17.append(json);
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your `productlist` is always empty.. and where you filled the data in list??

Comment: I have edited my full code,i cant send all the rows of list view to the server all time just last row of list view goes to the server...please see my code and suggest me where is wrong in my code and help me to solve my problem.

Comment: ok.. actually the String params are getting reset in each loop round, thats why it holds only last one... You need to perform the placeorder request in loop... can you put more than one product in single url request (like appending it to URL)

Comment: That can reduce your effort and avoid you to make multiple requests in loop

Comment: the answer Henry given is good. but it will make 4 asyncTask request if you have 4 items in cart.

Answer (score 0):

The few lines doing the sending should be inside the `for` loop:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < productlist.size(); i++) {
      productid[i]=productlist.get(i).getProductid();
      productquantity[i]=productlist.get(i).getProductquantity();
      product_qty=productquantity[i];
      product_id=productid[i];

      String placeorderquerystring = "?address=" + address + "&product_id=" + product_id+"&product_qty="product_qty;


      Log.d("Request : ", "starting 00 " + CC14.GETURL23 + placeorderquerystring);
      new GetPlaceOrder(Order_From_App_All_new.this, CC14.GETURL23 + placeorderquerystring).execute();
 }
```

Comment: I have tried this Henry  but i cant get any solution for my problem when i am doing this that u suggest me every time getting response and loader is not stopping if i have 4 products and i call from for loop i am getting 4 response page with different products...please help in another way

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the cart items as an JSON obj or array to server,

```
{  
  "Customer":"Name",
  "cart":"Cart ID",
  "date":"10-06-2016",
  "time":"3.36",
  "cartItems":[  
     {  
        "ProductID":"1",
        "ProductQuantity":"3"
     },
     {  
        "ProductID":"2",
        "ProductQuantity":"5"
     },
     {  
        "ProductID":"6",
        "ProductQuantity":"4"
     }
  ]
}
```

To get the above format, use the following code

```
private String getItems() {
       JSONObject dataObj = new JSONObject();
       try {
           dataObj.putOpt("Customer", "Name");
           dataObj.putOpt("cart", "Cart ID");
           dataObj.putOpt("date", "DATE");
           dataObj.putOpt("time", "TIME");
           JSONArray cartItemsArray = new JSONArray();
           JSONObject cartItemsObjedct;
           for (int i = 0; i < cartItems.size(); i++) {
               cartItemsObjedct = new JSONObject();
               cartItemsObjedct.putOpt("ProductID", cartItems.get(i).getId);
               cartItemsObjedct.putOpt("ProductQuantity", cartItems.get(i).getProductQuantity);
               cartItemsArray.put(cartItemsObjedct);
           }
           dataObj.put("cartItems", cartItemsArray);
       } catch (JSONException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch bloc
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return dataObj.toString();
   }
```